# Probability of receiving packets

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we send $n$ packets over the Internet and assume that all $n$ packets are routed along the same path, and with probability $p$, one of the links along the path fails and all $n$ packets are lost. Otherwise all packets are received..

What kind of distributions is this and how to compute the distribution and expectation of this model.

I have something like:

Let $X$ be the random variable of the number of packets loss. And $X$ can only be 0 or $n$.
So $P(X=0) = (1-p)^n$ and $P(X=n) = p$. But I don't recognize this distribution and don't really know how to compute the expectation of this if this is correct distribution.

Any help? Please

Comment: I think $(1-p)^n$ is wrong. Why $n$?

Comment: because there is no packet loss when all packets go through, then $(1-p)$ is the probability for each packet going through.

Comment: You said all the $n$ packets are lost with probability $p$. And there are only two cases: either all the $n$ packets go through, or none of them does, right?

Comment: The probability of losing 0 is _p_ when _n_ > 0, and 1 when _n_ = 0.

Comment: We can change the physical situation, and assume that with probability $p$ a given packet is lost, that there is independence (?), and that if one packet is lost, the message cannot be reconstructed, so all are lost. Then $P(X=0)=(1-p)^n$, as in the post, but $P(X=n)=1-(1-p)^n$. Again we have a modified Bernoulli, and the expectation is easy to write down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $n$ packets go through, with probability $1-p$. They don't go through with probability $p$.

If there's only one trial, then this is "re-scaled" Bernoulli distribution. $X$ takes on either $0$ or $n$. $P(X=0)=1-p$, $P(X=n)=p$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got some confusions to sort out there. You can *either* say that either none or all of the packets go through, *or* you can say that each has probability of $p$ to go through. It makes no sense to mix these two situations.

So if the situation really is as you describe it in the first paragraph, then $P(X=0)=1-p$ and $P(X=n)=p$; that's all there is to it. (Note that your distribution also couldn't have been right because it wasn't normalized to $1$.)